# Как записать все тексты из массиву ссылок в один файл?

Tags: python-3.x

Есть массив ссылок `x2`. Как мне записать все тексты из этих ссылок в один файл `ds1.html`?

```
for i in x2:
x3 = requests.get(i).text
with open("ds1.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(x3)
```

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: @Dareten он в файл ds1 записывает только содержимое самой последней сылки в массиве, а мне надо чтобы все тексты из всех сылок записались в этот файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x2 = ['https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014939', 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com'  ]

with open("ds1.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for i in x2:
        x3 = requests.get(i).text
        f.write(x3)
```

Comment: большое вам спасибо, работает